# Why mounted() gives me Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

When I try to initialize the browser's audio API, Vue.js gives me

> Error in mounted hook: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`

I made an Audioapi component that hold an audio tag.

```
<template>
  <audio controls></audio>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted () {
      var vm = this
      vm.$store.dispatch('Player/init', vm.$el)
    }
  }
</script>
```

When mounted, it call a function that initialize the Javascript part in the store. It creates the audio context and connect everything together.

```
const state = {
  myAudio: null,
  audioCtx: null,
  analyser: null,
  distortion: null,
  gainNode: null,
  biquadFilter: null
}

const mutations = {
  INIT (state, payload) {
    state.myAudio = payload
    // Create audio elements
    state.audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
    state.analyser = state.audioCtx.createAnalyser()
    state.distortion = state.audioCtx.createWaveShaper()
    state.gainNode = state.audioCtx.createGain()
    state.biquadFilter = state.audioCtx.createBiquadFilter()

    // Connect everything together
    state.source = state.audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(state.myAudio)
    state.source.connect(state.analyser)
    state.analyser.connect(state.distortion)
    state.distortion.connect(state.biquadFilter)
    state.biquadFilter.connect(state.gainNode)
    state.gainNode.connect(state.audioCtx.destination) // connecting the different audio graph nodes together
  }
}
const getters = {
}
const actions = {
  init ({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    commit('INIT', payload)
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

I put a `console.log` in the `mounted` and it's called only once. Everything need to be in the store as many other components will need access to those variables.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it's called only once? I'd expect it to be called infinitely since you're mutating `vm.$el` which should cause `mounted()` to be called over and over again. Maybe browser optimizations detect this and throw the error you're getting instead of console.logging many times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @connexo, how should I do this then?